# C++ Matrix to dynamic 2D arrray

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, dynamic-arrays

let's say we have a matrix in a matrix.txt  file, stored like this:

[image: Image1]

and we want to transform it into:

[image: Image 2]

Number 8 (first number) means how big will 2D array be. After that it means:
1 is connected to 2 (value of connection is 1, it will always be 1)
1 is connected to 8
3 is connected to 4

And when transformed into 2D dynamical array, we want the value 1 in ARRRAY 0,1...0,7...2,3   and soo on (i didnt use square brackets because stackoverflow read them as links).

```
    int number;
int **a = new int*[number];
for (int i = 0; i<number; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[number];
}
for (int i = 0; i<number; i++) {
    delete[]a[i];
}
    delete[]a;

string line;
ifstream myfile("matrix.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    getline(myfile, line);
     istringstream(line)>> number; 


    while (getline(myfile, line)){
        cout << line << '\n';
        //HERE I SHOULD TURN THOSE NUMBERS INTO VALUES IN 2D ARRAY
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

So my question is: **How do i turn this numbers into matrix in 2d array?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way, but possibly not the fastest way, is to write the line into a [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), then read back out of the stringstream into row, column, and value variables. If you are reading from a file the cost of reading the file in the first place usually dwarfs the cost of parsing the file the slow way. If it matters in your case (and profile the code first to make sure it does) look into manually parsing the file. That said, this basic logic will hold.

```
while (getline(myfile, line)){
    cout << line << '\n';
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    int row;
    int column;
    int value;
    if (linestream >> row >> column >> value)
    {
        a[row-1][column-1] = value;
        a[column-1][row-1] = value;// mirror
    }
    else
    {
        // handle file formatting error
    }
}
```

Off topic, consider using a matrix class to manage a for you rather than a raw 2D Array. [The matrix class here at isocppp.org is good and fast](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op), as well as wrapped in some very good general-purpose advice.

The above code with the isocpp matrix looks like:

```
while (getline(myfile, line)){
    cout << line << '\n';
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    int row;
    int column;
    int value;
    if (linestream >> row >> column >> value)
    {
        a(row-1,column-1) = value;
        a(column-1,row-1) = value;// mirror
    }
    else
    {
        // handle file formatting error
    }
}
```

Nearly identical and a lot easier to use because you don't have to worry about managing the memory yourself, passing the array dimensions around, or a bit of bad code (such as `a[4] = 0;`) nuking a row of your array.

## Addendum

This code

```
int number;
int **a = new int*[number];
for (int i = 0; i<number; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[number];
}
for (int i = 0; i<number; i++) {
    delete[]a[i];
}
delete[]a;
```

has two serious problems:

1. `a` is sized with `number`, and `number` hasn't been assigned yet. `number` could be anything from an instantly fatal negative number (can't have an array with a negative size) to a potentially fatal huge number (Your computer have 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 squared bytes of RAM? Didn't think so.)
2. It deletes the storage immediately after allocating it. Freeing the memory is a great habit to get into, but it's best to free the memory after using it, not before.

So:

```
// define `a` here
string line;
ifstream myfile("matrix.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    getline(myfile, line);
    istringstream(line)>> number; 

    // allocate storage for `a` here

    while (getline(myfile, line)){
        cout << line << '\n';
        //line reading code goes here
    }
    myfile.close();
}
// delete `a` somewhere down here after it's been used.
```

Comment: When it try to this way, i get a error saying that a is undefined.

Comment: All I supplied was the `//HERE I SHOULD TURN THOSE NUMBERS INTO VALUES IN 2D ARRAY` and the while loop around it. You still need the rest of your code to define `a` and open the file.

Comment: Unless you're going for the matrix version. In that case you need `Matrix a(number, number);` Come to think of it, you have a nasty bug in the definition of your array. Making an edit to help you fix that.

Comment: This works, the part where i deleted it was wrong, I had to move that to the end of the code. But I also had to make a change, code did add 1's to the right places, but the other places were "NULL", so i gave them all value 0 when created. Thank you :)

Comment: Good catch. One of the cool things about a `std::vector` is it does that zeroing (or whatever value you tell it to use) for you. Sometimes that's not so cool because it takes time an you may not want everything zeroed, but you can't please everyobdy.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use C++ vector from the STL instead of 2d C array which are unsafe.

You could do something like :

```
ifstream myfile("matrix.txt");

// Read matrix size
size_t matrix_size = 0;  myfile >> matrix_size;

vector<vector<int> > matrix(matrix_size);
for(size_t i=0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)  matrix[i].resize(matrix_size);
while( myfile.good() )
{
  // Read row,col,val and set matrix value
  int row=0, col=0, val=0;  myfile >> row >> col >> val;    
  --row; --col; // Since your indices go from 1 to N
  if(row < matrix_size && row >= 0 && col < matrix_size && col >= 0) {
    matrix[row][col] = val;   matrix[col][row] = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: More than unsafe. The vector is a lot easier to use, pass around inside the program, and clean up after than a dynamically allocated 2D array. That said, if you want good performance use a 1D vector and fake out the second dimension with `row * number_columns + column`. Read up on the impact of "cache misses" on a program.

Comment: If I have understood OP's file format the final matrix seems to be symmetric, with only the upper right part stored in the file...

Comment: Right @Bob__ I missed that point. The suboptimal solution is to add the same value in matrix[col][row]. A better solution would be to use a class to handle symmetric matrices with a one dimensional vector and the correct operator[] for access.

Comment: @steiner yes, it's a bit more challenging then the dense case ;) Maybe an overkill for OP's question/skill...